# Material Tab - cover selected tab border

Tags: css, sass, angular-material

I have this (rather ugly) styling for Angular Material Tab component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aciwzg?file=src/styles.scss

I want the selected active tab to have no `border-bottom`.

This isn't immediately obvious due to the border belonging to the Tab's Body(`.mat-tab-body-wrapper`) not the Tab itself.

I think I need to extend the height of the tab content to hide the bottom border.

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Is anyone able fork my stackblitz and achieve this using CSS only?

Comment: Glad I found this.  Been messing around for hours trying to get boxes drawn around all the tab labels to make it look like a regular tab control.  Your stackblitz put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use some tricks to make this work

**Hide the border of content under the tabs container**

to do this :

- move the bottom content wrapper `top: -1px`
- add the bottom border to tab like this: `border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;`
- remove the bottom border of tab container:  `border-bottom: none`

here is updated fiddle: <strike>https://angular-aciwzg-kjzfk6.stackblitz.io</strike>

updated link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aciwzg-kjzfk6?file=src/styles.scss

Comment: I can't access your Stackblitz. Can you check your link?

Comment: This solves it but would good if it was explained here in full without having to unravel the stackblitz